# Is java.dyn renamed?

Tags: java, dynamic

What happened to "java.dyn" package? I couldn't get it in java 1.7 in eclipse. Actually I just wanted to learn about *"InvokeDynamic"* and  try to run [this](http://oneminutedistraction.wordpress.com/2010/11/22/invokedynamic-bytecode-in-jdk-7/) example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it becomes [java.lang.invoke package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/package-frame.html)